# How do I assign network cards to specific users?

Tags: networking, windows-10, routing, network-adapter, network-traffic

OS: Windows 10 Pro

I have 2 Network connections available.
First is Ethernet, second is a LTE Router via Wlan.

Main goal:
Route specific program traffic through the wired connection while other programs should solely use the wireless connection.

Problem is the ip's or port ranges of the applications change often so a "route" solution is not very handy.

There is a tool called "forcebindip" but it injects into the process and this is a big no for me. Also some programs create child processes and forcebindip isn't able to do that afaik
(sadly - great tool though)

So I came up with this idea but I struggle with the implementation.

Create 2 Windows users lets call them uLan and uWlan.

Allow uLan only Lan connection, allow uWlan only Wlan connection 
Standard user should be uLan.
If I need to bind a application to Wlan i start it with "Run As.." uWlan.

Question is how do I assign network cards to specific users.
Could this even work or are there better solutions for my problem?

Comment: Windows’ network configuration is not tied to users. So no, that’s not possible. Unless your software supports specifying the outgoing interface or proxies, something like ForceBindIP is the only viable solution.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! A Firewall rule won't help either?